# Where does the coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ of $(-1)^p\frac{1}{2}\bar{\partial}_E^* = \bar{\partial}^*$ in $A^{0,q}(\Omega_X^p)$ come from?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Consider the holomorphic bundle $E=\Omega_X^p$ over complex manifold $X$. $\bar{\partial}^*$ is the formal adjoint of $\bar{\partial}$ with respect to inner product of differential forms.

As in *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry* by *Claire Voisin*, the end of *5.1.3*, *remark 5.11*, p.123, she says $(-1)^p\frac{1}{2}\bar{\partial}_E^* = \bar{\partial}^*$.

However I think
$2^p\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle_{A^{0,q}\ (\Omega_X^p\ )} = \langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle_{A^{p,q}}$. And
\begin{align}
\langle\bar{\partial}_E u,v\rangle_{A^{0,q}\ (\Omega_X^p)} &= \langle u,\bar{\partial}^*_E v\rangle_{A^{0,q}\ (\Omega_X^p)}  \\
&= (-1)^p2^{-p} \langle\bar{\partial} u,v\rangle_{A^{p,q}} \\
&= (-1)^p2^{-p} \langle u,\bar{\partial}^* v\rangle_{A^{p,q}}\\
& = \langle u,(-1)^p\bar{\partial}^* v\rangle_{A^{0,q}\ (\Omega_X^p)}
\end{align}
and therefore $(-1)^p\bar{\partial}_E^* = \bar{\partial}^*$.

My question is where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the book come from?

---

I realize that the main point is how the inner product is defined. Maybe for the inner product in $A^{0,q}\ (\Omega_X^p\ )$, the inner product of antiholomorphic differential form $d\bar{z}$ is induced by the Hermitian metric in $T_X$, while the inner product in $A^{p,q}$ is induced by Euclidean metric of $(T_X\otimes C)^*$ where the Euclidean metric is induced by hermitian metric of $T_X$. Am I right?

Comment: Side note : Claire Voisin is a she !

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Oh you are right!

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Could you please check out my recent editing and judge? Thanks!

Comment: Dear @XTChen, I have just noticed your last post about the Kodaira's vanishing theorem disappeared. Have you solved that problem?

Comment: @Steve No yet. Since cross posting is forbidden in Stack Exchange, I delete that one before posing in MO.

Comment: @XTOk, I will also pay attention to your post in MO.

Comment: @Steve I pose an answer in MO. You may check out. Or, I sincerely hope you could check out, ぜひ